# Node.js Asynchronous replace on string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using *node.js* and *express*.

I have a string similar to the following:

```
Here is my string but now I need to processString("mystring") 
and return the processString("data").
```

I want to search for all occurrences of processString and replace it with the results of a function.  The function I need to run is asynchronous.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so this is what I'm thinking I should do. Let me know if you think this is the right way or any better:   
1.  Do a regex match on processString  
2.  async.forEach over results  
3.  Do a string replace the regex match with the results from processString  
Does this seem right?

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't really to clear, the "why" and "what" may be more helpfull in answering your question.  From what I understand you want to replace `processString("****")` with `****` in which case you can use the following:

```
    var str = 'Here is my string but now I need to processString("mystring") and return the processString("data").'
    str = str.replace(/processString\(\".*?\"\)/gi, function(match){
         return match.replace("processString\(\"", "").replace("\"\)", "")
    })
    console.log(str);
```

This will match the `processString("****")` inner contents, hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Sorry, I tried to figure out how to make it as clear as possible, the parameter of the method needs to be processed by a function (processString) and it queries a database.  As the argument is from the user and can be anything, I can't avoid the database call.  So, the function that gets called has to be asynchronous.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I understand the question, however the source would help. With the understanding I have you can use case .replace() which is non blocking, so you can pass whatever paramaters you need through the callback, I think this would be the best way to iterate over the items in the string.  You could also avoid multiple queries by building a query index (collect all parameters), doing one query, and then replacing each result accordingly.

Comment: I don't have any code for it yet as I'm trying to figure out the best way for it to work.  If I use replace, is there a way to know when it is done so I can call the function's callback?